# Android: not displayed ImageView with UIL and TouchImageView

Tags: android, url, imageview, zooming

I'm trying to implement load images from a `URL` with `Universal Image Loader` and `zoom` with `TouchImageView Mike Ortiz`. But when trying to view the image, **black screen** is displayed. I have checked that the URLs are correct. I if I see a TextView there...

What am I doing wrong?

**ImagePagerActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    assert bundle != null;

    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray("urls");
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt("pos", 0);
    tipo = bundle.getString("tipo");
    monumento = bundle.getString("monumento");
    num = bundle.getInt("num");

    for(int i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
        // URLS with data
        Toast.makeText(this, "URL = " + imageUrls[i], 0).show();
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        pagerPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_POSITION);
    }

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.imagen)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.imagen)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
        .build();

    pager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_POSITION, pager.getCurrentItem());
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {

        this.images = images;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {

        final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ampliar_imagen, view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;

        imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.imagenFullScreen);

        infoImagen = (LinearLayout)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);
        info = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagenDesc);

        cargarInfo(position, images);

        android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LinearLayout infoImagen = (LinearLayout)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textoInfoImagen);

                if(infoImagen.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    infoImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    infoImagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}

private void cargarInfo(int position, String[] images) {

    if(tipo.equals("fotos")) {

        info.setText((position + 1) + " de " + images.length +
                "\n" + InfoImagenes.devolverInfoFotos(monumento, position, num, ImagePagerActivity.this));
    }

    else if(tipo.equals("planos")) {

        info.setText((position + 1) + " de " + images.length +
                "\n" + InfoImagenes.devolverInfoPlanos(position, num, ImagePagerActivity.this));
    }
}
```

**activity_full_screen.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <imagenes.ExtendedViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ampliar_imagen.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/negro" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <imagenes.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenFullScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/cargandoFoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textoInfoImagen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoInfoImagenDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

If I change TouchImageView by ImageView it display the image

Comment: Did you have solution right now? Please share it, I am also meet above problem

Answer (score 14):

I also met this problem, I found it is related with `ProgressBar`'s visibility, and the following code can be used to solve it.

- In `onLoadingStarted()`,  add `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)`
- In `onLoadingComplete()`, add `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

code:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri.toString(), 
                     mPictureView,
                     options,
                     new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
{
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) 
{
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) 
{
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
{
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks dear @cwc you saved my day.

Comment: issue is fixed, but how is it related ? m confused

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same issue. I've temporary solved the problem by resetting the zoom.

```
touchImage.setZoom(1);
```

inside onLoadComplete()

Of course touchImage is your TouchImageView object.

Comment: your temporary solution saved my life

Answer (score 5):

if set imageView  bitmap  async , i found matrix is {0,0,0}{0,0,0}{0,0,1} ,so image cannot be showed.. when imageView that have a null drawable  finished measure at first time, `TouchImageView.viewWidth`and `TouchImageView.viewHeight` is 0 .but when you setImageBitmap using a !null bitmap,the imageView cannot be measured again.`TouchImageView.viewWidth` is 0 at this time.see following code.

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)      {
        setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
        return;
    }

    int drawableWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int drawableHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = setViewSize(widthMode, widthSize, drawableWidth);
    viewHeight = setViewSize(heightMode, heightSize, drawableHeight);

    //
    // Set view dimensions
    //
    setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight);

    //
    // Fit content within view
    //
    fitImageToView();
}
```

if you load image from url or load image from local but use async mode by thread,you can change `TouchImageView.OnMeasure` as follows..

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
//        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()    == 0) {
////            setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
//          
//          super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
//          return;
//        }

    int drawableWidth = drawable == null ? 0 : drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int drawableHeight =  drawable == null ? 0 : drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = setViewSize(widthMode, widthSize, drawableWidth);
    viewHeight = setViewSize(heightMode, heightSize, drawableHeight);

    //
    // Set view dimensions
    //
    setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight);

    //
    // Fit content within view
    //
    fitImageToView();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem I was facing. I have solved the problem by setting zoom 0.99f as follows:-
**imageView.setZoom(0.99f);**

where imageView is reference of TouchImageView. I was facing this problem in ImageLoader, so I just put the above line in **onLoadingComplete** method. You can also put the same line before loading the image url  to **glide** or **ImageLoader** but better to put it after **loading complete**. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit follow it, It run in tab2 but other device is not, I don't know why

```
private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    ScaleListener scaleListner = new ScaleListener(); //Added

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, scaleListner); //Edited
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    prevMatrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    normalizedScale = 1;
    if (mScaleType == null) {
        mScaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;
    }
    minScale = 1;
    maxScale = 3;
    superMinScale = SUPER_MIN_MULTIPLIER * minScale;
    superMaxScale = SUPER_MAX_MULTIPLIER * maxScale;
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    setState(State.NONE);
    onDrawReady = false;
    scaleListner.onScale(mScaleDetector);//Added
    super.setOnTouchListener(new PrivateOnTouchListener());
}
```

or you change to, it will help you show the image, good luck to you

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(urlDownload, mImageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v(TAG, "Bitmap What "+loadedImage.getWidth()+ " "+loadedImage.getHeight());


            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with TouchImageView and dug through some relevant open issues on GitHub. If you are still keen on using TouchImageView, try something like this:

```
binding.imageView.load("some URI") {
            transition(CrossfadeTransition(preferExactIntrinsicSize = true))
}
```

OR I would suggest you use com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView ([implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'](https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView))

XML:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
     android:id="@+id/patient_wound_image"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

Activity or Fragment:

```
binding.dogImage.load("some URI")
```

The latter library provided the Pinch-to-zoom and Double-tap-to-zoom functionalities without any extra codes. Good Luck!